# Reading XML into a class that contains a List<Class>

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am reading an XML file using XDocument and loading it into classes. Each "site" node should be a class with the "tags" node being a List within it. I am having trouble loading the "tags" elements into the class as a List.

Here are the classes:

```
public class Site
{
    public string name;
    public string prefix;
    public List<Tag> tags;
}
public class Tag
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Column { get; set; }
}
```

This is the code that is loading XML data into the classes:

```
settings = XDocument.Load("settings.xml");
IEnumerable<Site> sites = settings.Descendants("site").Select(x => new Site()
{
   name = x.Element("name").Value,
   prefix = x.Element("prefix").Value,
   // How to load the "tag" elements into a List<Class>?
});
```

Using the following XML example:

```
<settings>
    <site>
        <name>name1</name>
        <prefix>prefix1</prefix>
        <tags>
            <tag column="col1">tag1</tag>
            <tag column="col2">tag2</tag>
            <tag column="col3">tag3</tag>
        </tags>
    </site>
    <site>
        <name>name2</name>
        <prefix>prefix2</prefix>
        <tags>
            <tag column="col1">tag1</tag>
            <tag column="col2">tag2</tag>
            <tag column="col3">tag3</tag>
        </tags>
    </site>
</settings>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) instead?

Comment: I was originally using XmlDocument but when doing more advanced XML readings I read that XDocument was a lot easier to use, which I found to be true. What advantage would there be in using XmlDocument?

Comment: Yes I would choose XDocument over XmlDocument; I suggested **XMLSerializer**, which does the serialization for you instead of crawling the XML.

Comment: Oh I thought XML Serializer required use of the XmlDocument class. I'll have to re-investigate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, at the location of your comment // How to load...  : (untested)

```
tags = x.Element("tags").Elements("tag").Select(r => new Tag() { Column=r.Attribute("column"), Value = r.Value } );
```

Comment: This solution should do it, but you might want to do a null value check on the element returned from "x.Element("tags")". You could also skip the select and just do something like "foreach (var element in x.Element("tags").Elements("tag")) { tags.add new Tag() { Column = element.Attribute("column"), Value = element.Value); }" it depends on what you are most comfortable with.

Comment: Thanks! Just had to make some minor tweaks and turn it into this:     tags = x.Element("tags").Elements("tag").Select(r => new Tag() { Column = r.Attribute("column").Value, Name = r.Value }).ToList()

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Playground
{
    public class Program
    {
        [XmlRoot("settings")]
        public class Settings
        {
            [XmlElement("site")]
            public Site[] Sites;
        }

        public class Site
        {
            [XmlElement("name")]
            public string Name;

            [XmlElement("prefix")]
            public string Prefix;

            [XmlArrayItem("tag", typeof(Tag))]
            [XmlArray("tags")]
            public Tag[] Tags;
        }

        public class Tag
        {
            [XmlAttribute("column")]
            public string Column;

            [XmlText]
            public string Name;
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (FileStream reader = new FileStream("mydoc.xml", FileMode.Open))
            {
                XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof (Settings));
                Settings o = ser.Deserialize(reader) as Settings;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Further reading:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.aspx (most importantly the XmlSerializer class)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.71).aspx

And Wikipedia article about XSD (can't post more than two hyperlinks yet).